# Will Silverlight's Deep Zoom Capabilities be available in Windows 8?

Tags: silverlight, windows-8, microsoft-metro

Will it be possible to write Deep Zoom metro apps in Windows 8?

Comment: Deep Zoom can be implemented in pretty much any language. The magic is the pre-processing that turns all those individual subimages/zoom stages into a useful data structure, and the code to dynamically load the images as you're zooming/panning around.

Comment: There are still not this kind of control in Windows Store app. Does anyone know what could be the first approach to create a custom control similar to Deep Zoom in c# ?

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't appear to be an analog to the [`MultiScaleImage`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.multiscaleimage%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) control in the [WinRT Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).  That doesn't mean it won't be there at release, however.

Also, there's nothing preventing you from rolling your own `MultiScaleImage` control, though I don't think that's what you meant in your question.